# email addresses SQL

Tags: sql

I need to update all email addresses in a table in such manner that if an email address is ending with gmail.com it should be replaced by hotmail.com

Comment: `replace('gmail.com', 'hotmail.com')` ? Please add your DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...) and show what you already tried, show where you fail.

Comment: A simple update query should work, assuming no one is crazy enough to have an email address of gmail.com@gmail.com - if they do, I says they get what they deserve (with all due respect to those who disagree). So you can (and probably should) add a where clause here, `... WHERE LIKE '%gmail.com'`

Answer (score 0):

This will work in SQL Server

```
UPDATE Table
SET emailAddress = Replace(emailAddress,'@gmail.com','@hotmail.com')
WHERE emailAddress like '%@gmail.com'
```

Comment: Will even work in most dbms's.

Comment: @jarih Thanks for the edit, forgot to change it after trying on my DB.